# Expose metrics for Kotlin using JMX_Exporter to prometheus

Tags: openshift, prometheus, grafana

I am trying to use JMX_Exporter for my kotlin code to expose metrics to prometheus in order to show it in Grafana. I have gone through many articles and tried to understand how could it be done. I have found below two links useful and trying to achieve using those.

https://github.com/prometheus/jmx_exporter
https://www.openlogic.com/blog/monitoring-java-applications-prometheus-and-grafana-part-1
What i did so far is, created a folder 'prometheus-jmx' in root directory and added mentioned JAR and config.yml file in that folder. Then, i added below parameter to my dockerfile.

```
CMD java -Xms128m -Xmx256m -javaagent:./jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.12.0.jar=8080:./config.yml -Dconfig.file=config/routing.conf -cp jagathe-jar-with- 
    dependencies.jar:./* com.bmw.otd.agathe.AppKt
```

My prometheus is running in my OpenShift cluster along with my application. I could scrape metrics for my other applications/deployments like Jenkins, SonarQube etc without any modifications in deployment.yml of Prometheus.

My application is running properly now on OpenShift and from application's pod, I can scrape metrics by using below command.

```
curl http://localhost:portNumber
```

But on promethus UI, I cant see any JVM or JMX related metric.

Can someone please tell me where and what am i doing wrong? Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

After trying many things, I came to know that I needed to expose the port of my application's container in order to let Prometheus or other deployments to know. After exposing the port, I could see my application under targets on Prometheus and I could scrape all JMX and JVM metrics. Hope this would help someone in future...